# vim: replace all character occurrences till other token

Tags: vim

Is there anyway to replace all "-" occurrences by "_" till "=" character?

Example:

```
BO.MONTHS-TO-DELETE-REFERENCE=1
-->
BO.MONTHS_TO_DELETE_REFERENCE=1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Would `:s/-\ze.*=/_/g` work?

Comment: It worked. How could I apply it to multiple lines? I played with recordings. Substituion are recorded as well?

Comment: By reading `:help :substitute` :-p Use `:%s/-\ze.*=/_/g` to operate on the whole buffer (=file) or select lines in visual mode with `V` and then `:'<,'>s/-\ze.*=/_/g` (Vim will fill in the `'<,'>` part for you)

Comment: Macros will record the exact keys you press, also substitutions. I used to record macros a lot when I started using Vim. For most common cases, substitutions are superior to macros.